# discriminate typescript union when at least one member has multiple discriminant values

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

I have a union type where a bunch of almost-identical members are grouped into a single interface with multiple discriminants, and some members are given their own interface. Notional:

```
interface Simple {
    type: 'foo' | 'bar';
    field: string;
}

interface Complex {
    type: 'quux';
    whoa: string;
    so: string;
    many: string;
    fields: string;
}

type All = Simple | Complex;

type DiscriminateUnion<T, K extends keyof T, V extends T[K]> = T extends Record<K, V> ? T : never;

// Works as expected:
type t1 = DiscriminateUnion<All, 'type', 'quux'>;

// `never` :(
type t2 = DiscriminateUnion<All, 'type', 'bar'>;
```

This `DiscriminateUnion` is the standard form that I'm aware of, but it can't discriminate the `Simple` member due to the multiple discriminant values, and devolves to `never`.

This example works if `Simple` is broken into two almost-equivalent types, one for each discriminant, but that is needlessly verbose for other usages of these types.

Is there a type that can work such that `t2` is resolved to `Simple`?

Comment: (Your naming of `K` and `V` are unconventional; `K` usually means **K**ey and `V` means **V**alue, but you've got them reversed.  Could you switch them so as to remove any distraction from your issue?) Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wQJbZN) meet your needs?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Fixed; thanks for spotting that. Your approach does work, both here and in the original context. I had actually tried both the `T extends T` distributive trick and `V extends T[K]` phrases before posting... just not at the same time! `T extends T` is still a bit mysterious.